# Custom PHP Template in Twenty Twenty-Four

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, templates

I am trying to use a custom php template in the latest theme and not only it has an file editor, there is no place for me to paste my template file.

This is a template file for a custom post type so I have specific fileds I capture at post creation be displaed in a specific manner. I need to use php functions before I render the page. Hence an HTML only file is not working for my purpose.

I tried searching for any assistance or resources, I couldn't find anything at all. Is this fucntionality being deprecated from WP?

Comment: I think the modern way is to build a block using PHP then include the block into your page as a comment in the HTML template that gets rendered when the page. But I'm not up to date here myself.

Comment: However I don't think you could ever just drop files into your theme using the admin site? If you want to extend or modify a theme you normally want a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), and that's probably where you should define your new block(s) too.

Comment: Here's the latest theme documentation which discusses block markup and theme.json: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/templates/introduction-to-templates/ Hoping someone who knows this all better than I do can post a definite answer.

Comment: That said if you just need to display extra fields from the custom post type I'd be very surprised if there weren't already built-in blocks, or readily available third-party blocks e.g. from ACF, that you can use do that already. You'd only need a custom block and PHP if you need to do any specific processing of the data for display.